# Как сделать, чтобы при наведении мыши на 2-ю звездочку заработал hover первой и второй звёзд?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении мыши на 2-ю звёздочку заработал `hover` первой и второй звёзд?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.stars {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.stars i:hover {
  color: aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="stars">
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-4x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-4x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-4x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-4x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-4x"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: измените сам вопрос, для того, чтобы участники поняли смысл вопроса, а не занимались решением ребусов. И учтите, "остальным" - пишется через "а".

Comment: Исправил нужно что бы при наведении на 2-ую звезду заработал hover 2-ой звезды и первой и так далее

Answer (score 2):

Пример реализации на `css`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.stars {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.stars:hover {
  color: aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stars .fa:hover ~ .fa:before {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="stars">
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-4x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-4x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-4x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-4x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-4x"></i>
</div>
```

В `css` нельзя выбирать предыдущие элементы, но можно следующие. Поэтому при наведении мы делаем голубыми все звезды, а черными делаем следующими за той, на которой ховер.

Comment: Вот ещё мой старый фидл на эту тему – https://jsfiddle.net/artemfs/kkceqmc1/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.rating {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-direction: reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating [for*=star] {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating [for*=star]:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.rating [for*=star]:before {
  content: '\f005';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.rating input:checked~[for*=star] {
  color: #DAA520;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5">
  <label for="star5" title="5 stars">5 stars</label>

  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4">
  <label for="star4" title="4 stars">4 stars</label>

  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3">
  <label for="star3" title="3 stars">3 stars</label>

  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2">
  <label for="star2" title="2 stars">2 stars</label>

  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1">
  <label for="star1" title="1 stars">1 stars</label>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас подсвечивает только одну звезду. Вопрос же про то, как подсветить не только её, но и всё, что левее.

Comment: @ Arhad  В данном ответе не прямой ответ.  Но все очень просто используя свойство flex-direction: row-reverse; Пример  https://jsfiddle.net/2o5yh1Lb/